# path.split strange behavior

Tags: go, filepath

it seems that there is an issue with the split method in path/filepath

I have looked at the debugger and it seems like it does not split the path into
sections

go version:1.19

debugger output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NHZ0.jpg

```
        case fsnotify.Rename:
                    dir, filename := path.Split(event.Name)
                    fileIndex := indexOfFile(filename, s.LoggedFiles[dir])
                    if fileIndex == -1 {
                        errChannel <- errors.New("file path does not exist in map")
                        break
                    }
                    s.LoggedFiles[dir] = append(s.LoggedFiles[dir], s.LoggedFiles[dir][fileIndex])
                    fmt.Println(s.LoggedFiles[dir])
                }
```

Comment: Use [path/filepath.Split](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Split) to split a file path.

Answer (score 2):

The [path.Split()](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Split) uses the `/` separator.
To split OS specific directories you should use the [path/filepath.Split()](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Split) that uses the [os.PathSeparator](https://os.PathSeparator).